# Convergence of Average Number of Distinct Values of i.i.d. Discrete Random Variables

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with a countable range. For simplicity, assume that there exists a sequence $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset[0,1]$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_k=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1=k)=p_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $Z_n$ be the number of distinct values in the set $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$. I am interested in the convergence of $Z_n/n$ as $n\to\infty$.

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3438272/602889), $\mathbb{E}Z_n/n=o(1)$ and $\text{Var}(Z_n/n)=O(\mathbb{E}Z_n/n^2)=o(1/n)$. Thus, $(Z_n-\mathbb{E}Z_n)/n\to 0$ in $L^2$, and hence $Z_n/n\to 0$ in $L^2$, in $L^1$, and in probability.

**My question:** Does $Z_n/n$ converge to $0$ almost surely?